# Difference between 'willst' and 'wilt' in 'Shakespearean' English?

Tags: word-choice, tenses, archaicisms, seventeenth-century-english

I am writing a scene from Macbeth detailing the battle before the play for my 11th-grade English class, and I decided to write it in Shakespearean for fun. I have been trying to figure out the difference between *willst* and *wilt*. Everything I have found tells me that they are alternating and second singular tense, but that's all I could figure out. Is it in any way similar to the distinction of *hast* and *hath*? (Where *hath* means 'has' and *hast* means 'have'?)

Answer (score 5):

There is more going on here than any of the previous answers has indicated.

The verb "will" as I believe you are using it is a modal verb (not to be confused with the regular verb "to will" meaning "to wish, want, desire" -- it's the difference between "He wills himself out of bed each morning" and "He will get out of bed tomorrow at nine").

The first usage of the verb "to will," albeit unusual today, is a regular verb that is inflected like all other regular verbs, taking the third-person singular ending, -s. But the second usage, as a modal verb, is not inflected in Modern English and remains the same for all persons and numbers (I/you/he/she/it/we/you/they will).

Modal verbs in Middle English used to be inflected, but by the time of Shakespeare's Early Modern English, modal verbs had largely dropped their inflected forms, except for the second person singular (thou).

So while "willeth" is the correctly inflected form of the third-person singular for the verb "to will," you most likely wouldn't inflect it as a modal verb. So keep it "he will..." With thou, however, you *can* use "thou wilt" and still be consistent with what is found in Shakespeare.

The same is true for modals in the past ("thou wouldst," "he would," etc.).

Answer (score 4):

"willst" isn't a real word.  Don't use it.

"wilt" is an archaic word, used in second person singular.  E.g. "I will", "Thou wilt", "He willeth".

"**hath means has and hast means have**" isn't quite right.
Again, they are archaic singular conjugations:  "I have", "Thou hast", "He hath".

Answer (score 2):

Shakespeare used *wilt,* not *willst.* [Open Source Shakespeare](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org), a search engine for Shakespeare's texts, turns up many results for *wilt,* but none for *willst* or *wilst.*

As user490759's answer says, *will* is usually a modal verb whose third-person singular form is *will* not *willeth* (*pace* Ray Butterworth's answer): thus "I will", "Thou wilt", "He will".